# Java Database Transaction Management

Tags: java, c#, database, multithreading, transactions

I would like a Java based transaction manager that can handle nested database transactions in a web environment (database calls from different classes can share a transaction, and thread safe).

I believe this is possible because I recall that C# has something roughly equivalent to this:

```csharp
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly String CONNECTION_STRING = "x";

        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                (new Person()).insertRecords();
                (new Hobbies()).insertRelatedRecords(); // Can see Person records
                transaction.Dispose();
            }
            (new Hobbies()).insertRelatedRecords(); // Can't see Person records
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public void insertRecords() {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Program.CONNECTION_STRING)) {
                conn.Open();
                // insert records
            }
        }
    }

    public class Hobbies
    {
        public void insertRelatedRecords() {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Program.CONNECTION_STRING)) {
                conn.Open();
                // insert records
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, I am hoping to illustrate my intent to exercise the code, "Person and Hobbies must both complete the transaction successfully, otherwise roll back both of their changes. Hobbies should be able to see the data inserted by Person because it happened first in the transaction." It is important that these are happening in different classes or methods, but managed from the parent without having to pass around a connection or transaction object.

My application currently runs on Tomcat and creates database connections using an Oracle pooled connection (OracleDataSource class). It doesn't use Tomcat's database context. A single user/schema/login is used for all connections.

Realistically I only have Java librairies available to use, as requesting new libraries takes months and requests are often denied. I do have Oracle and Tomcat right now, but these may be changed in the future, so my solution must be in pure Java. There are no plans to add Spring or Hibernate.

Here is a minimalistic version of the Java class structure in the application:

```java
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {
            Program program = new Program();
            (program.new Person()).insertRecords();
            (program.new Hobbies()).insertRelatedRecords();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    // Core classes //
    
    public static class DbDataSource 
    {
        private static DataSource dataSource;
        
        public static synchronized DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
            if (dataSource == null) {
                OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
                ods.setDriverType("x");
                ods.setURL("x");
                ods.setUser("x");
                ods.setPassword("x");
                dataSource = ods;
            }
            return dataSource;
        }
    }
    
    public class DbResource implements AutoCloseable
    {
        private Connection connection;
        
        public synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = DbDataSource.getDataSource().getConnection();
            }
            return connection;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Data base classes //
    
    public class DbClass 
    {
        private DbResource db;
        
        protected synchronized DbResource getDatabaseResource() {
            if (db == null) {
                db = new DbResource();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }
    
    // Data classes //
    
    public class Person extends DbClass
    {
        public void insertRecords() throws Exception {
            try (DbResource db = this.getDatabaseResource()) {
                // insert records
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Hobbies extends DbClass
    {
        public void insertRelatedRecords() throws Exception {
            try (DbResource db = this.getDatabaseResource()) {
                // insert records related to Person
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My goal is to implement this without changing the Data class (rewriting the Data base class is fine). The idea would be to have code that resembles how transactions work in C# (but I'm also welcoming a better proposed solution). Something like the following:

```java
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try (DbTransaction transaction = new DbTransaction()) {
                Program program = new Program();
                (program.new Person()).insertRecords();
                (program.new Hobbies()).insertRelatedRecords(); // Can see person records
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            (program.new Hobbies()).insertRelatedRecords(); // Can't see person records
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    // ... rest of the class ...
}
```

My current line of thinking include storing a static List or Map of transaction objects every time they are created, and pop them off when transaction.commit() is called (or the object is disposed and AutoCommit is on). However, this only works in a single threaded application (like many Desktop applications). I could restrict it to the current web session, by using a Map<Session, List>, but this is still not thread safe within the session. If a user opens multiple pages while they are still loading, this would fail to isolate them.

I'm not sure how to solve this for a web application that requires unique transaction lists for each scope/code stack. I don't believe there is any way to ask for instantiated objects within the current scope (that would include parent classes).

This is further complicated by pooled connections, where I cannot guarantee that any two calls share the same connection. However, if I could figure out a multi-threaded solution, I can worry about pooled connections separately.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle client already contains this functionality.  On your Oracle connection, run the `.setTransactionIsolation(TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED)` method to allow dirty reads within a transaction.  Then, disable auto-commit mode to allow you to manually commit or rollback operations on the connection using `setAutoCommit(false)`.  Alternatively, you could also use Savepoints.

All of these are detailed in [Oracle's JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, those are good options. Unfortunately, my database (or my driver?) doesn't support that isolation level. Savepoints do work, so that's something I'll experiment with. The bigger problem I still have is how to share the connection variable (ignoring the pool issue) without passing the variable into every method.

Comment: @Rapps - You could just declare a public static connection variable. However, that won't work in any kind of parallel processing, such as on a web server handling multiple requests.

I would actually recommend passing the connection into your lower level functions (or the class constructors that contain them). This will make your code much more robust. If you aren't familiar with it, dig into the concept of dependency injection for more reasons this is a good practice.

Comment: @Rapps - Also, I would highly recommend Spring or Spring Boot. It is so much easier than doing this stuff manually.

Comment: Yes, a public static connection variable is an option with a bit of creativity. I would use a map<id,connection> so I can uniquely identify each connection by some key (I'm thinking session id + thread id). Regarding dependency injection, I do have something equivalent to it in my inheritance chain. The data classes all acquire a connection from an inherited method. Both dependency injection and Spring/Spring Boot would require writing half of the application, which isn't really an option. The application is around 15 years old, so it's quite large.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend passing the connection down from the highest layer into every lower layer rather than using a map.  The map approach has to worry about thread safe access and handle the condition where the connection can't be found.  Since you already have the connection at the highest level, just add it to each lower class constructor or method.  Obviously you don't have to do it this way, but I think you'll thank yourself if you do.